# How to create consensus matrix?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I need to create a consensus matrix. Let say I have a matrix `A` as following.

```
1 1 2 2 3 
1 2 2 2 3
1 1 2 3 3
```

Each row represents one clustering method, and each value represent one specific cluster. For example, `A(1,1)` means that by firs clustering method, first data example assigned group one. By using this matrix, I need to create a matrix as follow

```
1/3 2/3 0/3 0/3 0/3
2/3 1/3 1/3 1/3 0/3
0/3 1/3 1/3 2/3 0/3
0/3 1/3 2/3 1/3 1/3
0/3 0/3 0/3 0/3 1/3
```

In this matrix C ,`C(1,2)` created based on Matrix A. More clearly, A(1,1) and A(1,2) in group 1, also A(3,1) and A(3,2) in group 1 as well. So, C(1,2)=2/3. Diagonal is just fixed as 1/3.

Comment: What if cluster numbers change? i.e. 2 2 3 3 1 is the same as the first, isn't it?

Comment: I think `C(5,4)` should be equal to 1/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bsxfun` to compare the columns

```
C=squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@eq, A,permute(A, [1 3 2]))));
C(logical(eye(size(C))))=1;
C = C/3;
```

You first permute your `3x5` matrix to a `3x1x5` matrix, then using `bsxfun(@eq, ...` you compare columns of the original matrix, and then sum up the locations where the elements on two different rows where equal by using `sum(...,3)` which gives you a `1x5x5` matrix. Now use squeeze to get rid of the singleton dimension.